# Editing a NSBezierPath in Cocoa Application

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am trying to draw a graph with `NSBezierPath`functonality. How do I remove the first and last line added to a `NSBezierPath`? Is there some direct method to achieve that?

**Update**

I'm drawing an arc using appendBezierPathWithArcWithCenter. Then I draw lines from center on both sides to complete the path to fill that. Now I need a path with the two lines removed. I don't want to create another bezier path consisting of only the arcs.

Comment: What do you mean by the first and last point? Why do you need to remove them? Is it purely for drawing purposes (could the path be masked)?

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist see update. A function is returning me a bezier path and I want only a particular section with last drawn straight lines removed.

Comment: Have you considered having one path with the arcs and use `appendBezierPath:` to add that path to the path with the two lines?

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist no. i draw arcs at specific radius and then make lines to the end points. i don't know the start and end point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't remove individual elements of an `NSBezierPath`. You can only edit existing elements or remove all of them. The best choice for your case would be to copy all elements (except the unwanted) to a new path.

If the path is very long and there might be a performance concern you could move the first and last points to match the second and second last point. This would not result in exactly the same drawing, though:

```
NSInteger elementCount = [path elementCount];
if (elementCount > 2) {
    CGPoint points[3];
    [path elementAtIndex:1 associatedPoints:points];
    points[1] = points[0];
    points[2] = points[0];
    [path setAssociatedPoints:points atIndex:0];

    [path elementAtIndex:elementCount - 2 associatedPoints:points];
    points[1] = points[0];
    points[2] = points[0];
    [path setAssociatedPoints:points atIndex:elementCount - 1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider modifying function which returns you the path.
Within NSBezierPath you can only modify associated with path elements points (see [NSBezierPath setAssociatedPoints:atIndex:]), but not the path elements type.